# Model class only popups on first button when used in append

Tags: javascript, html, model, popup, append

I am using Material UI to build a website. I have append a list with data and it also has a popup on button. But the popup works only on first button click.

I want to make a new popup on every button click. Also here is a error from console.

"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'showModal' on 'HTMLDialogElement': The element already has an 'open' attribute, and therefore cannot be opened modally.
    at HTMLDivElement."

Here is HTML

```
<div id="order">
                    <dialog style="width: 40%;" class="mdl-dialog">
                        <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                            <table id="table" style="width: 100%;" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Unit price</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody style="width: 100%;" id="producttable">

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                            <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Confirm Order</button>
                            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Order Shipped</button>
                            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Order Delivered</button>
                            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Order Canceled</button>
                        </div>
                    </dialog>
                </div>
```

Here is JS

```
$("#order").append(
                '<div style="padding-top:6px; padding-bottom:6px; margin-bottom: 16px;" class="card-wide mdl-card-order mdl-shadow--2dp"><h3 id="orderID" style="margin: 16px;" class="mdl-card__title-text">' +
                '<a style="float: left; width: 65%;">Order ID : ' + orderid + ' </a><a style="float: right; width: 35%;">Date : ' + orderDate +
                '</a></h3><div style="margin-left: 16px;"><p id="client_name" style=" font-size: 18px;"> Name - ' +
                name + '</p><p id="client_email" style=" font-size: 18px;">Phone -  ' + phone +
                '</p><p id="client_email" style=" font-size: 18px;">Address -  ' + address +
                '</p></div><div class="mdl-card__menu"></div><div id="dialog" class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border"> <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" onclick="purchaseList(' + orderid + ')"> Purchase List </a></div></div>');

function purchaseList(listid) {

var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('Orders/' + listid).child('foodItems');
starCountRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {

    var snaps = snapshot.val();
    var itemPrice = snaps.price;
    var itemName = snaps.productName;
    var itemQuantity = snaps.quantity;

    console.log(itemName);
    $("#producttable").append(
        '<tr><td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">' + itemName + '</td><td>' + itemQuantity + '</td><td>' + itemPrice + '</td></tr>'
    );
});

var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#dialog');
if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}
showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function () {


    dialog.showModal();

});
dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function () {

    var element = document.getElementById("producttable");
    while (element.lastChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
    }
    dialog.close();

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it is the point but

```
dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener(...
```

wont work with multiple classes. You have to use the

```
classList.contains('close')
```

for example but i would just give an id to the .close element to get it easy

```
<button type="button" id ="close" class="mdl-button">Confirm Order</button>
dialog.querySelector("#close");
```

or even better generate your HTML tag elements in JS to have direct access like

```
const closeBtn = document.createElement("button");
closeBtn.className = "mdl-button";
closeBtn.type = "button";
dialog.querySelector(".mdl-dialog__actions").append(closeBtn);

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  //Todo on click
})
```